# Double monitors, different scales

Tags: ubuntu, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, ubuntu-unity

I have recently replaced one of my 24' monitors with a 32' 4K. Here is my current `xrandr` output

```
$ xrandr               
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 297mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Of course the different resolutions don't play well. Playing with `unity tweak tool` and setting `text scaling factor` to `1.45`, I managed to have a nice configuration on the bigger monitor. However of course the scaling affects the smaller one as well and now the fonts are annoyingly large.

Is there a way to scale the two monitors separately? The ideal solution would be the one that leaves unchanged a window dragged between the monitors.